# scrape data from infinite scrolling page using scrapy?

Tags: python, ajax, web-scraping, scrapy

The response url while scrolling down is:

https://dir.dummymart.com/impcat/next?mcatId=20467&prod_serv=P&mcatName=laser-cutting-machines&srt=97&end=116&ims_flag=&cityID=&fcilp=0&pr=0&pg=5&frsc=28

The response data is in ajax like this:

```
{"page_var":"<div id=\"page_variables................
```

My spider code is :

```
import scrapy


class DummymartSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'dummymart'
    allowed_domains = ['dir.dummymart.com']
    start_urls = ['https://dir.dummymart.com/impcat/industrial-machinery.html',
            
                ]

    def parse(self, response):
        Company = response.xpath('//*[@class="lcname"]/text()').extract()
        product = response.xpath('//*[@class="pnm ldf cur"]/text()').extract()
        address = response.xpath('//*[@class="clg"]/text()').extract()
        phone = response.xpath('//*[@class="ls_co phn bo"]/text()').extract()

        for item in zip(Company,product,address,phone):
            scraped_info = {
                'Company':item[0],
                'Product': item[1],
                'Address':item[2],
                'phone':item[3]

            }
            yield scraped_info
```

How do i scrape datas that are loaded after the page is scrolled down? Also the data is in ajax not json. Thanks

Comment: Find what action is taken (probably an xhr request) when the scrolling is triggered and emulate doing that...?

Comment: Use a headless browser (like selenium and [headless Chrome](https://duo.com/decipher/driving-headless-chrome-with-python)).

Comment: sorry i am new to it so do you know any understandable document or blog link?

Answer (score 0):

You can approach in two ways:-
1. Use a headless browser like Selenium or if you are working in Scrapy then you can also try Splash which allows you to run js function via scrapy.
2. Just Scroll the page to the point up to which you want to scrap the data, download that page as HTML and then run your normal code.

The second approach is little manual but if want to just scrap a few pages then I would suggest you go with the later one only.